# String.format query

Tags: java, string, format

I was messing around with String and formatting earlier today and have found an API oddity.

Usually when I am formatting a string I use

```
String.format("mystr %s", 1);
```

or something similar.

Now this [static method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is also accessible to instantiated objects of this class. The code below shows the result of using `String.format` statically and using `format` method directly from an object.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals("abc 123", String.format("abc %s", 123));
    assertEquals("abc 123", "abc".format("abc %s", 123));
    assertEquals("def 123", "abc".format("def %s", 123));
}
```

The last assertEquals() bascially overwrites the first "abc" string which I do expect looking at the signature of format.

Am I missing some funky usage of using the static method from the instantiated object. Or is it just visible because the static String.format() is also accessbile to the instantiated objects of String? In other words an API oddity/bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All static methods can also be called on instance of their class.

Using this feature is generally not recommended (many tools track it) but this isn't really a bug.

Comment: agreed it's not a bug..but just an API oddity I think

Comment: It's more an oddity of the Java language than of the API. They should have forbidden that but it's too late...

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, that has basically answered my question. It's an oddity of Java

Comment: @RNJ, usually your IDE will give you a compile-time warning, e.g. `The static method format(String, Object...) from the type String should be accessed in a static way`

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are always accessible via class instances (objects), there's nothing special about `String.format`.